# KDE plasma partial screen after unplugging hdmi second screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, arch-linux, kde, kde-plasma-5

I have arch with KDE plasma on my laptop. Yesterday I tried a second vga screen using a hdmi-vga adaptor (my laptop has only hdmi entry).
Everything worked fine, I used the second screen as an extension of the left border of the main one.
I then unplugged the cable and turned off my laptop. Today this is the situation after booting:

[image]

The black area is not accessible with the pointer or keyboard.

I can't access the settings or do anything else via desktop environment and I don't know how to move in this way with tty.

Is there a way to reset this behavior?

More info: laptop resolution 1920x1080,
Secondary screen resolution 1600x1200.
I'm now at the library without possibility to attach anything via hdmi...

UPDATE1:
I tried to reboot several times, deleted ~/.kde4 folder, restarted plasmashell, reset to default screen settings (using the few pixels available on the screen). Nothing changed.

UPDATE2:
Plugging in the hdmi cable (even without monitor) the problem disappears. When I unplug it comes back. No progress so far. Logging in as root does not show this behavior.

SOLUTION:

A solution would be resetting your user's KDE modifications to defaults, to do so open a terminal and type

```
mv ~/.kde ~/.kde.old
```

Log off, then log in with the same user. The ~/.kde folder and KDE settings will de recreated to default.

Comment: SOLVED deleting kde home folder for desktop settings.

Comment: I have the same problem; what folder needs to be deleted?

Comment: After a deleting the ~/.kde folder, and combination of restarting my laptop and disconnecting my 2nd display, and then restoring the ~/.kde folder, I was able to fix it.

Comment: Enkouyami is right, my commment was not precise, sorry

Comment: Will one of you please post a complete, clear and unambiguous answer *as an answer*?

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=410229

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve had the same problem on openSUSE Leap 42.1, but didn’t want to delete all my desktop settings (and KDE on openSUSE doesn’t have a „.kde“-folder, only “.kde4”, the deletion of which of course didn’t do anything, deleting kde-related things in .config didn’t help either).

Here is what I did to solve the problem without deleting any other settings:

Comparing the contents of ~/.local/share/kscreen/ of my account with that of a new account showed that instead of one file, there were six with names like “2b70a6fd3b2743573dc02a7767a1512d“ and “2b70a6fd3b2743573dc02a7767a1512d_lidOpened“. The contents of the files showed that some of them contained completely wrong resolutions and x/y positions.

With the second screen plugged in via hdmi, I deleted all files in there. KDE immediately recreated one file “2b70a6fd3b2743573dc02a7767a1512d“ which included the correct resolutions and positions for both screens.

After logging out and back in, I could unplug the hdmi and everything works as expected. Still works after rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

**Toggling projection** (FN key + F7 on my laptop) solved it for me.

Decided to contribute this answer as it's easier to to see if toggling projection solves the issue *before* trying other methods listed here like deleting KDE config.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what @PGMario said, on KDE 4.14.22, (Ubuntu 16.10) simply

1. Deleting:

   ~/.local/share/kscreen/
2. No need to restart, if you can plug/unplug the screen, otherwise log in again.

Thats it. Then using KDE screen display (open it using `kcmshell5 kcm_kscreen`) lets you set things up again.

It had in my case old screen settings that probabbly clashed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried a reboot. So, maybe you have a Button (mine Laptop has it) where you can change the screen settings. Like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFW4M.png)?

Where you can choose between - only use second screen, dont use second screen or double screens. Maybe this helps (even if there is no second screen ;-) )

Comment: I have the key but it didn't work.. Thank you anyway